# Add type to unknown function name of a inherited class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract `Lock` class which inherits `MorticeLock` class. The `MorticeLock` can decide how it names its public methods, but it should follow certain guidance: The first parameter always has to be a `string` called `key`.

```
abstract class Lock {
   // ["any public method"]: (key: string ...args: any[]): => LockResult;  
}

class MorticeLock extends Lock {
  public unlock(key: string, options: object): LockResult;
}

class AnyLock extends Lock {
  public crack(key: string, material: object, options: object): LockResult;
}
```

How can I enforce that any public method of the classes which inherit `Lock` always use `key: string` as first parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that in TypeScript.

If you're locked in to using classes, what you *can* do is add another layer of indirection - although this won't enforce the return type.

```
abstract class Lock<T> {
    private readonly viewCache: Record<string, T> = {};

    protected abstract createViewImpl (key: string): T;

    public createView (key: string): T {
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.viewCache, key)) {
            this.viewCache[key] = this.createViewImpl(key);
        }
        return this.viewCache[key];
    }
}

class MorticeLock extends Lock<MorticeLockView> {
    protected createViewImpl (key: string): MorticeLockView {
        return new MorticeLockView(key, this);
    }
}

class MorticeLockView {
    private readonly key: string;
    private readonly lock: MorticeLock;

    public constructor (key: string, lock: MorticeLock) {
        this.key = key;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public unlock (options: object): LockResult {
        // We now have access to the key and the lock object, but no longer have to
        // enforce the first parameter being a string
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hmm I would need this check during compilation to prevent unexpected behavior in production. According to the SO dislike votes and your answer it does not seem to be possible in TS. Thanks anyway :)